# Specify the directory of migrations of each entity manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-migrations

i've a multy-database project using symfony 4 and i want to make the migrations of my db1 in a folder called for ex : db1Migrations and the same for db2Migrations.

i did some researchs about the subject but all i found is about the symfony2 so i couldn't figure it out how to practice that on symfony 4, i'm new in symfony :)

if just someone could explain to me how that works i would be grateful !

[Symfony2 - Change Migration Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17066670/11831616)

[Migrating multiple databases using doctrine2 with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6844153/11831616)

My doctrine.yml

```
 orm:
    default_entity_manager: main
    entity_managers:

        main:
            connection: main
            mappings:
                Main:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                    alias: Main

        dossier:
            connection: dossier
            mappings:
                Dossier:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Dossier'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Dossier'
                    alias: Dossier
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code

Comment: Sorry i didn't know !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using symfony's DoctrineMigrationBundle: [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) try creating your migrations via console:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em=customer
```

instead of

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Here is [How to Work with multiples Entity Manager and Connections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

---

**EDIT:** I still think this is the correct answer. If you use the console command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em=dossier
```

It will use you ORM config. Follow the [Documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html) here just to make sure you have the right configuration in ***doctrine_migrations.yaml***

```
doctrine_migrations:
# List of namespace/path pairs to search for migrations, at least one required
migrations_paths:
    'App\Migrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/App'
    'AnotherApp\Migrations': '/path/to/other/migrations'
    'SomeBundle\Migrations': '@SomeBundle/Migrations'
```

Comment: thank's, but that's not the pb, i'm trying to save my "customer_db" migrations in a new folder !
when i run : php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em=customer the migrations will be saved on the default folder (Migrations) and all i want is to save them in a another path, i want to separate customer migrations and main migrations !

Comment: I'm also expecting the same behaviour but it didn't work as expected in Symfony 6.4 & doctrine-migration-bundle 3.0