# How to use different connection settings when running Doctrine migrations in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I have Symfony project with pgSQL DB.

I have two db users, one with select/update privileges for web (lets call it `usr_web`) and a second one with create/alter table for migrations (`usr_admin`).

I'd like to use `usr_web` for frontend of my web and `usr_admin` for running migrations via `doctrine:migrations:migrate`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434908/5884988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would just to use different environments for the migration and frontend processes.

Assuming you have the default Symfony 4 settings for doctrine:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

And that these settings are stored in your `.env` files, then you could have a `.env.migration` file in your root path with something like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://usr_admin:admin_password@db_host:5432/db_name
```

This file wouldn't be read normally (and you should probably make sure this file is gitignored so it doesn't end in your repo). But when executing a migration, you would just do:

```sh
APP_ENV=migration bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate
```

and the command would run using the "admin" credentials instead of the main ones.