# How is it possible to generate doctrine migrations for both mysql, mssql and sqlite?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I would like to generate database migration scripts using [doctrine migrations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.0/reference/introduction.html).

One of my customers have mysql database, the other one has mssql, and we use sqlite in our dev environment.

If I generate the scripts using `php artisan doctrine:migrations:diff`, then it will start with this line:

```
$this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');
```

How is it possible to generate migration script from the changes in our entity classes in a way, that it can be used on mysql, sqlsrv and sqlite as well?

Comment: if you have those databases installed, run the command with another database configured, change "abortIf" to "skipIf", and it should be alright I guess? Or you can use the `$schema` given to the migration to *manually* make it db agnostic.

Comment: @Jakumi I could generate the script for each database type, and then manually change/merge them, but It takes a lot of time to do this before each commit, and I am lookig for a simpler way to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using only sqllite in dev, you can create a `dev/doctrine.yml` file that declares three entity managers (one per database engine) as [described in documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). Of course, you only do it in development file. Don't alter your production configuration file.

Then, you create an env variable to specify the default orm to use in dev:

```yaml
# config/packages/dev/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: '%env(my_current_orm)%'
# ...
```

At this step, you are now able to change database server/engine only by changing an environment variable.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844153/migrating-multiple-databases-using-doctrine2-with-symfony2), you can create one `doctrine_migration.yaml` file per database engine. In these files, you specify different subdirectories to store your migrations files.

```yaml
#example for mssql engine
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/mssql'
    # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
    # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
    namespace: DoctrineMigrations/MsSql/
```

At this step, you are now able to launch migration commands for each database engine.

```sh
symfony console doctrine:migrations:status --em=mssql \
         --configuration=src/config/packages/dev/migrations/mssql.yml
```

As you see, for migration, I did **not** use the environment variable. I manually specify the default orm `--em=xxxx` and I specify the configuration file. I used this in an old project, but I think that it's now possible to use the environment variable in the `doctrine_migration.yaml` file to optimize configuration and have only one file.

*edit:(I remember that I have updated the module loader to avoid to load multiple times the migrations config files, you perhaps have to move the non-sqlite doctrine_migration configuration files in another directory than the usual one)*